# Avoid iterating through every row in Pandas for custom aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have a pandas DataFrame with two columns: `salary` and `food_perc` (the percentage of salary you spend on food). Each row corresponds to a different person.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Set seed
np.random.seed(1)

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'salary': np.round(np.random.uniform(10000, 100000, 100), 2),
                   'food_perc': np.round(np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.9, 100), 2)})
```

I want a new column called `food_compare` where for each person, I see how their `food_perc` compares to people with similar incomes (+/- 10%).

Because the +/- 10% cohort will be different for every person, I don't see a way to avoid iterating through each row and creating the cohort every time, as below.

```py
for i in df.index:

    # Isolate the cohort
    df_sub = df[(df.loc[:, 'salary'] * 0.9 < df.loc[i, 'salary']) &
                (df.loc[:, 'salary'] * 1.1 > df.loc[i, 'salary'])]

    # Make the comparison
    df.loc[i, 'food_compare'] = np.divide(df.loc[i, 'food_perc'],
                                          np.mean(df_sub['food_perc']))
```

Subsetting the dataframe for every iteration is really not a scalable solution. **Unfortunately, I can't preemptively create static bins (e.g. $10,000-$20,000, $20,001-$30,000, etc.) for the problem I'm working on.**

Is there a way to do some sort of `.groupby` when you don't have a discrete key? Otherwise I'm not sure what to do besides maybe sorting the rows by `salary` beforehand and modifying the subsetting step so it doesn't search through the whole dataframe when constructing the cohort. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a way around it with that requirement. Is there any reason it truly needs to be a percentage based window centered on each row, or could it suffice to compare rows within the same quantiles of salary? (in which case you can do one quick `groupby`)

Comment: @ALollz The end product involves looking up a person, with one of the metrics being this comparison to similar people. The issue with static bins is that if you're at the bottom or top of a bin, the bulk of the comparison group is fairly different from you, and there's some subjectivity in how you set bin cutoffs. Maybe those drawbacks are fine if we're trying to scale to 100,000s of rows and iteration isn't possible. But I want to first check whether this rolling window percentage is possible before arguing for static bins. I agree static bins would make this a much simpler question!

Comment: True, I agree with those issues. But sadly, all of the `.rolling` calculations assume a static window size, and `.groupby` ensures that elements can only belong to a single group, neither of which will help in this case. Hopefully someone else has an imaginative solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a count of each peer group,  you could do use this:

```
data['sal_peer_group_count'] = \
     data['salary'].apply(lambda x: len(data.loc[(data['salary']>.9*x) & \
                                       (data['salary']<1.1*x)]))
```

To get the peer group average of `sal_perc`

```
data['peer_group_food_perc_mean'] = \
     data['salary'].apply(lambda x: data.loc[(data['salary'] >.9*x) & \
                                             (data['salary'] < 1.1*x), 'food_perc'].mean())
```

Keep in mind that if you have any items of `salary` that are equal to zero and you would like them to be in the same group, you will need to modify the statement to be:

```
data['peer_group_food_perc_mean'] = \
     data['salary'].apply(lambda x: data.loc[(data['salary'] >.9*x) & \
                                             (data['salary'] < 1.1*x) \
                                              if x != 0 else \
                                              (data['salary'] == 0), 'food_perc'].mean())
```

Answer (score 1):

`pd.cut` was designed for this sort of thing: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

`df.groupby(pd.cut(df["salary"], np.arange(0, df["salary"].max(), 1.0e5)))`

Comment: `pd.cut` isn't useful here because it creates pre-defined static bins (i.e. `np.arange(0, df['salary'].max(), 1.0e5)`. The goal requires different bins for each row. Thanks, though - static bins are an increasingly attractive alternative.